# NginX 1.16 - URL redirections for one wordpress category and all its products

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url, redirect

I'm trying to rewrite this non existing url:

http://myshop.com/medical

to this working wordpress url:

http://myshop.com/shop/category/medical

(but visitor must not see the full wordpress url)

.
.
.

And by other hand I need to rwwrite the url products from that category:

http://myshop.com/medical/my_friendly_unique_url_product

to:

http://myshop.com/shop/category/medical/my_friendly_unique_url_product

```
server {
    root /var/www/myshop.com;
    server_name myshop.com www.myshop.com;
    include global/global.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;
    location /medicals {
        # http://myshop.com/medicals
        # to
        # http://myshop.com/shop/category/medicals/
        rewrite ^/medicals$ /shop/category/medicals break;

        # http://myshop.com/medicals/dinamic_unique_url_product
        # to
        # http://myshop.com/shop/category/medicals/dinamic_unique_url_product        
        rewrite ^/medicals/(.*)$ /shop/category/medicals/$1 break;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your apache rewrite rules do not perform rewrites like you have shown in your question. The `http://myshop.com/medical/my_friendly_unique_url_product` request will be rewritten to `http://myshop.com/shop/my_friendly_unique_url_product`, not the `http://myshop.com/shop/category/medical/my_friendly_unique_url_product`.
To perform the same rewrites with the nginx, try this:

```
rewrite ^/medical(?:/category/?(.*)|/?)$ /shop/category/medical/$1;
rewrite ^/medical/(.+) /shop/$1;
```

To rewrite the `http://myshop.com/medical/my_friendly_unique_url_product` request to the `http://myshop.com/shop/category/medical/my_friendly_unique_url_product`, use this instead:

```
rewrite ^/medical(?:/category/?(.*)|/?)$ /shop/category/medical/$1;
rewrite ^/medical/(.+) /shop/category/medical/$1;
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution, but I can`t make it work

Comment: 1. This rules won't work being placed into the `location` block, they should be placed at the `server` context. 2. This rules won't work if you invoke the PHP via `fastcgi_pass` directive. That's because the WordPress relies on the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable that isn't get changed with the `rewrite` directive (it is an `$uri` one that does). You'll need to redefine that variable **after** the `include fastcgi_params;` directive, e.g. `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;`.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using add_rewrite_rule wordpress function, put this code in functions.php theme or in a plugin:

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();    
    add_rewrite_rule( '^medicals/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?product_cat=medicals&paged=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^medicals/(.*)/?', 'index.php?product=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'medicals/?$', 'index.php?product_cat=medicals', 'top' );
} );

function prefix_filter_news_permalink( $url, $post ) 
{ 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    $nterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag'  );
    foreach ($terms as $prod_term) {
        $product_cat_id = $prod_term->term_id;
        if ( $product_cat_id== 540 ) { //my medicals ID category
            return trailingslashit( home_url('/medicals/'. $post->post_name ) );
            break;
        } else {
            $product_parent_categories_all_hierachy = get_ancestors( $product_cat_id, 'product_cat' );  
            foreach($product_parent_categories_all_hierachy as $last_parent_cat_value){
                if ($last_parent_cat_value == 540 ) { //my medicals ID category
                    return trailingslashit( home_url('/medicals/'. $post->post_name ) );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'prefix_filter_news_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).